# Map of <Int, int*> in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I want to make a map that have keys as integer like 0,1,2,3 and each of keys values to be a variable array of integers let says

```
map[0] = {0,1,2};
map[1] = {0,1,2,3,4};
```

how to achieve this in C++

Comment: C++ doesn't have variable length arrays, but it has `std::vector`. So use those instead.

Comment: If your keys are contiguous from `0`, you may use `vector` instead of `map`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `<map>` and `<vector>`:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> m;

m[0] = {0, 1, 2};
m[1] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Comment: @hariszaman: No problem. Jarod42's comment above is useful; if your keys are sequential starting at 0, then a vector of vectors is more efficient than a map of vectors.